# Trouble parsing JSONArray within JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

For some reason i could get the whole array read back but when i try to select one segment it doesn't let me see past past the segment in the array the array length equals 1, like it all got squashed into one element. This is my code:

https://github.com/yehudaclinton/Mytest/blob/master/TestHTTP.java

> ```
>             try {
>                 Object obj = parser.parse(result);
>                 JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
>                 JSONArray items = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("items");
>                 Log.d(TAG, "items length: " + items.size());//for some reason is not more than 1
>                 String name = "";
>                 //the the following is supposed to return just the title of book
>                 for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
>                     JSONObject item = (JSONObject) items.get(i);//if 'i' equals more then one program crashes
>                     if(item.get("title")!=null) {//only get the title
>                         JSONObject theTitle = (JSONObject) item.get("title");
>                         name = (String) theTitle.get("title");
>                     }
>                 }
> ```
>
> result = name;

Comment: What is the stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

I just called the url you've got in your code `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=lTrump&maxResults=1` and the 'items' array is only of length 1 anyway. Try removing the &maxResults=1 from the url?

So use this url instead `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=lTrump`

Answer (score 0):

It is really simple... change the:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=lTrump&maxResults=1
```

to:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=lTrump&maxResults=[someNumber]
```

And you will get more than one item

Comment: When you have problems like this one, try to use http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ or something similar. Then you can check if the problem is in your JSON response or the code itself. 

I called your Api end point and I got only one item... that's your problem

Answer (score 0):

actually you all missed it but here is the answer to my problem

```
                Object obj = parser.parse(result);
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
                JSONArray items = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("items");
                JSONObject first = (JSONObject) items.get(0);
                JSONObject volumeInfo = (JSONObject) first.get("volumeInfo");
                String name = (String) volumeInfo.get("title");
```

basically i didn't get the JSON hierarchy correct and i was calling a non existent element